# JAVA proper lat/long coords for google street view URL

Tags: java, coordinates, gis, google-street-view

I am currently working on getting coordinates from my application and being able to lookup/display the street view of that location. I am doing so by getting the lat long of a point in my application, then building a url from parameters as shown here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro My issues is that I know my coordinates are on a street due to the nature of the application, however google maps url saids "sorry we have no imagery here" when attempting to visit the url to display the picture. code below:

```
IGeometry shape = closestStationOrSpanFw.getIFeature().getShapeCopy();
    IPoint point = null;
    if (shape instanceof IPoint) {
        point = (IPoint) shape;
    }
    double xCoord = point.getX();
    double yCoord = point.getY();

    System.out.println("original X coordinate: " + xCoord);
    System.out.println("original Y coordinate: " + yCoord);

    GeometryUtil.projectLatLong(point);
    System.out.println("new coords: " + point.getX() + "        " + point.getY());
```

I think there may be an issue with the spatial reference I am using? (i.e: I'm using a different coordinate system than google maps API) but from what I've read this is not the case

note that point.getSpatialReference().getName() will print "GCS_North_american_1983"

and an example of a failing url here: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=-87.858763145,34.6677027164

Comment: The coordinates you provide are in Antarctica

Answer (score 1):

Try to move to that coordinates with google map, not google street view. Probably it is far from a road.

**Actually -87° is only 3° over the south pole!**

Check here: http://www.latlong.net/c/?lat=-87.858763145&long=34.6677027164

and zoom minus many times to see where you are!

Comment: yes my issue was in fact that I was using the x coord for lat and y coord for long when it should be vice versa. problem is now solved. upvote for the helpful resource

Answer (score 1):

from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes:

Google uses the World Geodetic System WGS84 standard.

Comment: yes my issue was in fact that I was using the x coord for lat and y coord for long when it should be vice versa. problem is now solved. upvote for the helpful resource